# Assign background image url to a div within a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function, drawPlaceDetails that assigns values to a html template.
 getPhotoURL() function returns a url link to the image.
 I need to assign this url to background-image property. 
 All I get is an empty div with no image. I have validated the url's by printing    them to the console and they seem to open up an image.

The template code and function is as follows:

```
<script type="text/html" id="places-template">
  <li>   
  <div class="placesCard">   
    <div id= "places-name" class="places-name">${name}</div>
    <div id= "places-img" style="height:40px;width:40px; border:1px black solid"></div>
    <div id="places-address" class="places-address">${formatted_address}</div> 
  </div>  
</li>
```

```
function drawPlaceDetails(results){
 $("#places-list").append("<ul></ul>");
 for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
 var result = results[i];
 console.log(result);  
 var photo = getPhotoURL(result.photos);    
 $("#places-template").tmpl(result).find("#places-img")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + photo + "')";
 $("#places-template").tmpl(result).appendTo( "ul" );
 }
}

function getPhotoURL(photos){ 
  if(photos){
  return photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 35, 'maxHeight': 35});     
}
```

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is right ? .appendTo( "ul" )

Comment: Could you please share the console.log details to debug easily?

Comment: Yes. Because the other elements are getting appended properly to "ul"

Comment: @NagaSaiA : I am not getting any error on the console but neither is the image getting appended.

Comment: console.log(result);  - what is the output of this console.log??

Comment: @NagaSaiA:  "result" is an object obtained from using Google Places API which has fields such as: {formatted_address: "1075 Tully Rd #32, San Jose, CA 95122, United States", geometry: Object, icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png", id: "1c5dc234baffda29dec83b094b3b806e8f88befe", name: "Little Caesars Pizza"…}
formatted_address:"1075 Tully Rd #32, San Jose, CA 95122, United States"

name:"Little Caesars Pizza"
photos:Array[1]
place_id:"ChIJkyfsN-oyjoARYaF41nKnA5w"
price_level:1
rating:3.7
}

Comment: This `result` console.log is strange... Show how you get it. I mean, how you get `results` (the array)

Comment: So what actually gets inserted in the live html? Inspect that as well as use dev tool network to see what image url is actually being requested (if any)

Comment: @charlietfl : I get blank boxes as shown in the image above after assigning the background-image .

Comment: Can you do console.log(photo); after the line that gets the photo url ? @user2585118

Comment: That tells us nothing about using browser dev tools to inspect the live html...not what you can see...we already know the images aren't there

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your problem.**

I took this from your comment above.
Assuming it is the console.log() of `console.log(result);`

```
{formatted_address: "1075 Tully Rd #32, San Jose, CA 95122, United States",
 geometry: Object,
 icon: "maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/…;,
 id: "1c5dc234baffda29dec83b094b3b806e8f88befe",
 name: "Little Caesars Pizza"…}

 formatted_address:"1075 Tully Rd #32, San Jose, CA 95122, United States"
 name:"Little Caesars Pizza"
 photos:Array[1]
 place_id:"ChIJkyfsN-oyjoARYaF41nKnA5w"
 price_level:1
 rating:3.7 
}
```

This is a mal-formed object.
Many missing `,` and an extrat bracket `}` after `"Little Caesars Pizza"`

I can't say about the `...` within this object.
It looks like you hide some code.

**EDIT**

Try to get this `restaurant-71.png` that I now see in your edit (console snapshot):

```
var photo = result.result.html_attributions[0].icon;
console.log(photo);
```